# python function only returns: <function x at 0x1215fd3a0> - how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

Hello I have just started learning python, I keep getting stuck here: this is a data frame of titanic passengers, I want to sum all the ages of the survivors, however I need to exclude all 'nan' values from my calculations. This code does not return an error but <function age at 0x1215fd8b0>. I have also tried print age() but that gives me a syntax error. Any ideas? Thanks

```
survivors = titanic[titanic['Survived']==1]

def age():
    summ=0
    for age in survivors.Age:
        if surivors.Age is float:
            summ+=age
        else:
            summ=summ
    return(summ)
print(age)
```

Comment: "exclude all 'nan' values" -- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a sample of the titanic dataframe. It would also be useful to know what your expected output will be. In short, if you can give us a workable sample to work with, we can hopefully help you along.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *call* the function. And maybe learn about the `sum` function

```
survivors = titanic[titanic['Survived']==1]

def age(survivors):
    return survivors['Age'].dropna().sum()
print(age(survivors))
```